# PostExecute not firing in SSIS script component

Tags: sql, ssis, script-component

I have a Source Script Component in SQL2012.
I believe if you want to set a Read/write variable in the Scriptcomponent it must be set in the Postexecute method .  And I have done so like this;

```
    public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    Variables.value1 = "some value";
}
```

I tested the variable after the script component ran and found it hadn't been set.  I set a break point in the PostExecute method and confirmed it never gets called.

I even wrote a very simple new package and tested it again with the same results.  Can anyone tell me why the PostExecute will not fire.

I'm not aware of any restrictions on seting a variable here (regardless of if there are records to process or not).

Answer (score 0):

The variable can be set in the script component, but you can only use it after the Data Flow task is finished (in the next task).

Comment: How does that prevent the event from firing ?

Answer (score 0):

After some testig it appears that when you use a script component as a "Source" the PostExecture event never fires.  Works fine a "Transformation".  Didn't test out "Destination" type.  Nothing in the Microsoft documentation mentions this fact so it's missleading.

I ended up using the rowcount control to count records.  Not sure what I would have done if i had needed to to more on the PostExecture event.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Script Component as a source many times and PostExecute does fire.

Comment: You may need to give some details!

Comment: This seems to be a "cannot reproduce" comment. It surely does not solve OPs problem. For this kind of (in itself not inappropriate) comment, please use a comment, not an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead